# Dumping address of a c-string to an ostream?

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

I am learning pointers and I dont understand how pointers work with C-style strings. 
Why are these two equivalent?

```c
char a[] = "Gme";
char* p = a; //Why am I allowed to assign "Gme" to a pointer (pointer is an address)

cout << p << " " << *(p+1); //Why does it print "gme" with "cout<<p" (I mean, I am printing an address)?
```

and

```c
char a[] = "Gme";
char* p = &a[0];   // How is this the same as char* p = a;

cout << p << " " << *(p+1);
```

Overall, I do not understand how pointers work with strings. How are chars stored in memory? If we consider string as an array of chars,why can't I print the address of a char element?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: arrays in c are just pointers to a buffer implicitly allocated on stack (if not in global scope)... nothing else. that's why you can use pointer and char array

Comment: @V-X: Arrays in C are not pointers.  `sizeof(a)` is proof of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really anything to do with them being C-style strings. It's true for any array. For example, you can do:

```
int arr[10];
int* p = arr;
```

The reason you can do this is because there is a standard conversion called *array-to-pointer* conversion. This converts an expression denoting an array (such as `arr` above), into a pointer to its first element. We know the first element of `arr` is an `int` so the pointer we get from this conversion is an `int*`.

```
char a[] = "Gme";
char* p = a;
```

In this example, we know `a` is an array of `char`. It has 4 elements: the letters `G`, `m`,  `e`, and the terminating null character. When you initialise `p` with `a`, you are performing array-to-pointer conversion to get a pointer to the arrays first element. The first element is the character `G`, so `p` is a pointer to that character.

`std::cout` (and the rest of the standard I/O library) just has special overloads for when you output a `char*`. Instead of simply printing the address that the pointer contains, it assumes that the pointer is pointing at the first character in a null-terminated string (and usually it is correct). It gets each letter of the string just be incrementing and dereferencing the pointer you have passed.

Comment: Thank you very much.. This was the best answer. I now start to understand. Though there are some misunderstandings, I can figure out myself now.. You did the most job. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

> Overall, I do not understand how pointers work with strings. How are chars stored in memory?

This is a large topic that has already been answered.

[What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c) is a good starting point.

---

> If we consider string as an array of chars,why can't I print the address of a char element?

You can.  You just need to do some extra work to clarify to the compiler what it is you want.

There is an [overload for the `<<` operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) that takes an ostream and a `char*` which interprets the right operand as a NUL-terminated string.

If you want `cout << ...` to only see the pointer-ness of `p`, and not its stringy-ness then cast to `void*` so that the only options available to the function call dispatcher when choosing which [`operator<<` overloading](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) to use are the ones that perceive it as a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

A C-String is an *array* that consists of `char` elements.

An array is a series of values in memory which cannot be stored in a single variable (since variables generally have a limit of 64 bits), so the variable **points** to the first element in the array (eg. contains the address of the first element).

So 
char `a[] = "Gme"` creates an array consisting of "G", "m" and "e" stores it in memory, and `a` contains the address of the first element ("G" in this case).

`char* p = a;` is valid because `a` was implicitly created as a pointer, so you are just re assigning the address of the first element of the array to p.

`char* p = &a[0];` is valid because a[0] is the **value** at the 0'th element of `a`. By adding `&`, you are taking the **address** of the 0'th element of `a`. So p now points to the first element of the array `a` so now p can be treated as an array as well.

Comment: no.  Arrays Are Not Pointers.  `a` does _not_ contain the address of anything, because `a` is an array.